# Hive/hdfs plugin authentication for policy sync with ranger admin ( viarestapi)

Tags: plugins, hive, hdfs

I am using ranger admin in separate EC2 instance. I have a EMR cluster with hive , hdfs plugin. Both are talking to each other and working as expected.

My question is what user does the hive/ hdfs plugin use for making rest API calls for fetching policies from ranger?

I could see some audit entries in ranger audit that "admin" user is used to execute curl commands.But this happens once and I do not see any calls later.  However, later I deleted admin user after creating another admin user with different name.

What is involved in this rest authentication? Who and how is it getting authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the post in the link.This might answer your query:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/212490/will-hive-caches-all-the-apache-ranger-policies-pe.html

https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.0/installing-ranger/sec_installing_ranger.pdf